# Migrating data from SQLite3 to Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, sequel

I am working on a rails app and need to migrate my data from SQLite3 to Postgres. I tried using the sequel gem by following this [tutorial](http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/migration-to-postgresql-on-rails)

But when i run `sequel -C sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://keemtaker:password@localhost/tuma_development`         I get this error

> Databases connections successful
>
> Migrations dumped successfully
>
> Error: Sequel::DatabaseError: PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "applicants" already exists

The error seem to point to one of the tables in schema but have no clue how to solve this. This is my db:schema

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180220173537) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "applicants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "job_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "full_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "mobile_number"
    t.text "cover_letter"
    t.string "resume"
    t.index ["job_id"], name: "index_applicants_on_job_id"
  end

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "website"
    t.string "location"
    t.string "address"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "photo"
    t.string "logo"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_companies_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "company_industries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "company_id"
    t.bigint "industry_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_company_industries_on_company_id"
    t.index ["industry_id"], name: "index_company_industries_on_industry_id"
  end

  create_table "company_perks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "company_id"
    t.bigint "perk_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_company_perks_on_company_id"
    t.index ["perk_id"], name: "index_company_perks_on_perk_id"
  end

  create_table "industries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "role"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "requirements"
    t.string "duties"
    t.bigint "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "job_type"
    t.string "keywords"
    t.string "salary"
    t.string "equity"
    t.text "pitch"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "location"
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_company_id"
  end
```

This is my database.yml

```
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tuma_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: keemtaker
  password: 'password'

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tuma_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: keemtaker
  password: 'password'


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: tuma_production
  timeout: 5000
  pool: 5
```

Comment: Are you sure the target schema is empty when you execute the migration? It seems it is trying to re-create the tables

Comment: the tables do exist. But there is no data. I have run rails db:migrate and rails db:seed. But the data did not move from sqlite3 to postgres